# Pausing audio player when youtube video loads in Elementor

Tags: javascript, video, elementor, background-music

I have a client, I'm working in Elementor, I have a mp3 file I'm playing via `var audio = document.getElementById("myaudio");` for background music, and I have a video in the header my client wants people to see when they click it. My issue, my background audio plays over my video.

I know  I can use CSS classes to define the area to be clicked (gave it a class named `headervideo`), I have a `pauseAudio()` function that will pause the video, I'm just not code savy enough to make `headervideo`=`pauseAudio()` when clicked. I'm sure I need a `addEventListener` or something very simple like that, but I just cant quite wrap my brain around it.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do it this way.

```
var video = document.getElementById("yourVideo");
video.addEventListener('play', function() {
    audio.pause();
});
```

Comment: This seemed to have worked for me! Just in time too, client liked it, thank you!!